# Put all the layers together in a document in Photoshop

Tags: photoshop, layer

I'm 24 images that have opened in photoshop layers  (size=300*200).

To create an image 6 * 4 (width=1800 , hight=800 )
I want all the layers in a document distributed and come together.
Doing this manually with a large number of photos will be difficult and time-consuming
Is Photoshop has the capability to automatically and accurately.

thanks .

like this image :
http://car20.com/images/social.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Go to

```
> file > Automate > File Merging and choose the option you want..!
```

you can also use the

```
> file > Scripts > Image processor if you have saved resize action select and run.!
```

[image]